# Google Analytics Goal Not Tracking Events

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I have an event that is showing clicks using gtag, and I set up a goal to track clicks on a submit button, but they are not loading on my goals view in Google Analytics

A couple weeks ago I converted from ga to gtag for event tracking, and I am getting results in events, but setting up a goal as an event isn't showing results. I have reviewed the documentation at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration and recently added 'send_to': 'UA-xxxxx-x' to my code

GA Goals set up like:

- Category - Equals to - Forms
- Action - Equals to - Button Click
- Label - Equals to - Start Free Trial
- Value - Greater than - 0

  ```
  <input type="submit" value="Start Free Trial"
  onclick="gtag('event', 'Button Click', {
    'send_to': 'UA-xxxxx-x',
    'event_category': 'Forms', 
    'event_label': 'Start Free Trial',
    'value': 'Free Trial Click'
  });" id="submit">
  ```

This does work to track the event, however goals are not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Measurement Protocol Parameter Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ev), which lists the parameters accepted by Google Analytics regardless of the tracking method (ga.js, gtag.js), the Event Value is a non-negative integer. This is also noted on the gtag.js [event tracking guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events). However, you are assigning a string to it, which will be ignored, and no value is sent to Google Analytics, resulting in zero event values.

Your goal setting requires a value greater than zero, this is why event goal requirements are not met. So you need to adjust your code and send greather-than-zero integer values, if this is a relevant parameter to fulfill the goal conditions. Or, you need to adjust the goal settings, and remove the event value setting, and only look at category, action and label.

Comment: Thank you, just switching that value to a "1" and it tracked in my live view, I really appreciate it